# Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-calendar-api

I am trying to add events to my calander using a service account. Currently I am able to add but it throws following error if I invite attendees as "Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority."

But I am using my personal gmail and I don't have any G-suite domain with me. How to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### This is not possible

You won't be able to use this feature with a personal gmail account. This is an intended limitation. Also, it's reserved to Google Workspace domain administrators.

The only solution for your current situation is to set up your application to use your personal account and not a Service one.

### Reference

[Perform Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials#optional_set_up_domain-wide_delegation_for_a_service_account)